# Link three tables to on Foreign key

Tags: sql, foreign-key-relationship, erd

[image: ERD]

From this ERD could anyone tell me what the best way to connect the Modifier, Monster, and Equipment tables to the card table.

I cannot just give have those tables have a FK of CardID because a Card may be the same Card, but have a different illustration, which would make the Card Unique but not the ModifierID, MonsterID, or EquipmentID.

And I don't think you can have null foreign keys either.

Is there any other way besides three more many to many tables?

Comment: Without requirements as to what this is supposed to model, it's very difficult to tell.  What is the relationship (in plain English) between Modifiers, Monsters, Equipment, and Cards?

Comment: Is Card Illustration linked to Card Expansion?

Comment: Perhaps have another tabled called something like "Card Illustrations" with a FK in "Card". You can then do whatever other business logic you need to couple an Illustration to an Expansion or some such.

Comment: It seems like there is no other way then by making many to many tables to link equipment, modifiers, and monsters to the card table.